# File delete action if condition exists

Tags: chef-recipe

New to chef recipe and google is not showing me an example of what I need to do.

I have a file that I want deleted when chef finds it exists.

I am not finding any google examples of something like

```
file /path/foo do
action delete
end if /path/foo exists
```

and the chef file documentation is not showing anything like
    file /path/foo do
    condition exists
    action delete
    end

Is the only way to use a script like bash?

```
bash 'delete_foo' do
    if [ -f /path/foo ] then
       /bin/rm /path/foo
    fi
end
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
file '/path/foo' do
  action :delete
  only_if { File.exist? '/path/foo' }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It will delete file only if it exists and do nothing otherwise

```
file '/path/foo' do
  action :delete
end
```